# js-ctypes and c# unmanaged dll in windows xp

Tags: c#, firefox-addon, unmanaged, jsctypes

I have a unmanaged c# dll (using Giesecke Dllexport). When I open this dll with js-ctypes in Windows 7,8 64/32 bits it works, but if I try it on Windows XP i get the error: "couldn't open library".

I made this dll using .Net Framework 2.0.

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MinhaDll
{
    public class Dll
    {
        [DllExport("getA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static string getA()
        {
            return "a";
        }

        [DllExport("getB", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static string getB()
        {
            return "b";
        }
    }
}
```

It's like this question, but it doesn't helped me:

[Unmanaged DLL Export with Robert Giesecke Library Not Working Under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849836/unmanaged-dll-export-with-robert-giesecke-library-not-working-under-windows-xp)

Comment: Hey there, you didn't get much attenion on this because the tags arne't frequently browsed by the jsctypes folks, tag on firefox-addon for more attention. :)  This is a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

I created a new DLL x86 from scratch in C# using DLLExporter by RGiesecke and .NET Framework 2.0, and now this works.

Comment: Can you please post the before and after source. I think the before is up there, it would be awesome to see the after so we can help others with similar situations

Comment: @Noitidart the problem was not in the code, but in project configuration. I changed to .Net Freamwork 2.0 and configured release to x86, then it works.